# how can I combine my own datasets and "wiki_dpr" provided by huggingface?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, tensor, wiki

I tried to add the document I found to the "wiki_dpr" dataset provided by "https://huggingface.co/datasets/wiki_dpr ", but I couldn't find a way to get the embedding value from that dataset.

I am currently trying to combine wiki_dpr and my own datasets.
but I don't know how to make the embedding value the same way as wiki_dpr.

As an experiment, I embed the text of id="7" of wiki_dpr, but this result was very different from wiki_dpr.

I executed the code below.

```
!pip install datasets evaluate transformers\[sentencepiece\]
!apt install libomp-dev
!pip install faiss-cpu
!pip install -U sentence-transformers
from transformers import DPRContextEncoder, DPRContextEncoderTokenizer

\#data
add_dpr_index = "7"
add_dpr_title = "Aaron"
add_dpr_text = "in literature dating to the Babylonian captivity and later. The books of Judges, Samuel and Kings mention priests and Levites, but do not mention the Aaronides in particular. The Book of Ezekiel, which devotes much attention to priestly matters, calls the priestly upper class the Zadokites after one of King David's priests. It does reflect a two-tier priesthood with the Levites in subordinate position. A two-tier hierarchy of Aaronides and Levites appears in Ezra, Nehemiah and Chronicles. As a result, many historians think that Aaronide families did not control the priesthood in pre-exilic Israel. What is clear is that high"

tokenizer = DPRContextEncoderTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base")
model = DPRContextEncoder.from_pretrained("facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base")
input_ids = tokenizer(add_dprtext, return_tensors="pt")\["input_ids"\]
embeddings = model(input_ids).pooler_output
print(embeddings)
```

I expected the result of the code to be a vector value of

```
[0.12092622369527817, 0.4741949737071991, -0.3044947385787964, ...]
```

but the different values came out

```
[5.3140e-01, 2.9851e-01, -5.3120e-01, ...]
```

and this means that the way is different.

Where can I get an embedding model specific to `wiki_dpr`?